# Maintenance plan SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, configuração

Criei um maintenance plan no banco da empresa em que trabalho, o mesmo esta tratando as seguintes opções:

- Check Database Integrity
- Shrink Database
- Reorganize Index
- Rebuild Index
- Update Statistics

E após a conclusão setei para que ele enviasse e-mail para um operador cadastrado, no primeiro momento ele estava dando o seguinte erro:

> Could not generate mail report.An exception occurred while executing a
>   Transact-SQL statement or batch.No global profile is configured.
>   Specify a profile name in the @profile_name parameter.

Esse problema consegui resolver deixando o operador público e o perfil padrão, de acordo com o histórico de execução não existe mais nenhum tipo de erro, mesmo assim ainda não estou recebendo e-mail após a execução do processo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Sei que é antigo, mas Shrink Database é extremamente não recomendado fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se certifica que não tem alguma porta bloqueada de envio de emails no servidor. Uma outra opção também é olhar o "mail queue" do servidor que esta enviando o email. Pode ser que esteja rejeitando por algum motivo que vc vai verificar lá.